# Dojo Toolkit (Dijit) example does not work in Stack Snippet

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

This snippet is adapted from http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/dojo_data/demo/store-adapter.html.

The snippet works in FireFox, but Chrome gives a browser error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.(…)(anonymous function) @ VM1360 DataGrid.js:198
```

```js
var data, grid;
require([
  "dojo/store/Memory",
  "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
  "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Memory, ObjectStore, DataGrid){
  data = [
    { abbr:'ec', name:'Ecuador',           capital:'Quito' },
    { abbr:'eg', name:'Egypt',             capital:'Cairo' },
    { abbr:'sv', name:'El Salvador',       capital:'San Salvador' },
    { abbr:'gq', name:'Equatorial Guinea', capital:'Malabo' },
    { abbr:'er', name:'Eritrea',           capital:'Asmara' },
    { abbr:'ee', name:'Estonia',           capital:'Tallinn' },
    { abbr:'et', name:'Ethiopia',          capital:'Addis Ababa' }
  ];
  var objectStore = new Memory({
    data: data
  });
  grid = new DataGrid({
    store: ObjectStore({objectStore: objectStore}),
    structure: [
      {name:"Country", field:"name", width: "150px"},
      {name:"Abbreviation", field:"abbr", width: "120px"},
      {name:"Capital", field:"capital",width:"100%"}
    ]
  }, "grid");
  grid.startup();
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/_common/demo.css" media="screen">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css" media="screen">
 <style>
  #grid {
   width: 400px;
            height: 15em;

  }
 </style>

<div class="claro">
<h1>Demo: Store Adapter</h1>
<div id="grid">
</div>
<!-- load dojo -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

</div>
```

Comment: Looks like cross origin errors, maybe Firefox is less strict about it?

Comment: Probably cross-origin errors, but I think they can be fixed on SE's side: similar jsfiddles work in Chrome.